# Google Cloud speech-to-text, how to silently throw UnknownValueError?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, speech-to-text

I'm making a Flask application which will ask User's to record a video of themselves, and then I want to transcribe those videos using Google Cloud Speech-to-text, and keep the transcription data.
Now the speech-to-text works well, but when some audio is too poor or has a lot of background noise, it throws this error:

```
if "results" not in response or len(response["results"]) == 0: 
raise UnknownValueError()
speech_recognition.UnknownValueError
```

I'm wondering if there's a way to configure it so that, if there's a word or sentence to confusing, it just moves on silently and tries to transcribe the next part. I'd rather have 25% of a bad video transcribed than none of it.
Any advice? Thank you in advance